# How get XAP name from Silverlight application with MEF?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, navigation, mef, dynamically-loaded-xap

I am writing Silverlight 4 application with Navigation framework and MEF.
In my application each menu for navigation must load on MEF project and show it.
But there are some problems. First of all I can't navigate to page of other XAP(see [David Polls post](http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/07/14/silverlight-3-navigation-navigating-to-pages-in-dynamically-loaded-assemblies/)). To do that I need DynamicNavigation.dll and must create extra pages, which is not acceptable in my case. Other soluction can be found on [davidezordan.net](http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=1734). This version is looks much better.
Second problem for me is that example works great if there is on additional XAP, but if I load 2 or more XAPs(by clicking on menus for navigation), I can't decide which page to show.
If 2 XAPs are loaded **MEFModuleList** contains 2 pages and I can't get any information about them to decide which page to show.
One solution is to hard code XAP name of each project in pages, which will be loaded to **MEFModuleList** by Attribute or other way, but it is not good solution.
Is there any other way to solve this problem?